# Ruby convert hexadecimal to character and print (Unicode Hebrew)

Tags: ruby, unicode, character, hex, hebrew

Hello I am working on a project that requires analysis of Hebrew characters.

I have a case like so

```
letter = case

         when (a[0] == "1") && (a[1] == "2"): "He ה"
         ...
         end

p letter 

=> "He ה"
```

I want to also print the Hebrew character from Unicode hex number (for He 05D4), like so:

```
letter = case
         when (a[0] == "1") && (a[1] == "2"): "\05D4 He ה" 
         ...
         end

p letter 

Desired output => "ה He ה"
Actual output => "\005D4 He ה"
```

Ruby 1.8.8.  $KCODE = "u" is set above code.

What do I need to do?  I have tried a few different things to no avail (e.g., ['05D5'.hex].pack("C") ) => error char out of range

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is your debugging code. `Kernel#p` writes *object*`.inspect`, and that tries perhaps a bit too hard to show you internal structure.

Just use a real I/O method like `puts` and I think you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I used puts and now the output is "D4 He ה" .  Aargh.